# AsyncTask problems with XML file creation problems

Tags: android

I'm making an app that is like a quiz.

When you select the answer and give it to the next in the background should send a response xml file and move to the next question (activity)

this is the code of the activity that calls the background task and passes the second activity

```
if(options == "0") ans.setText("Must select an answer");
        else {

           Intent intent =
                 new Intent(PM1_1Activity.this, PM1_2Activity.class);


           AsyncLoadXML carga = new AsyncLoadXML(PM1_1Activity.this);
           carga.execute();

           startActivity(intent);
           finish();

        }
```

This is the code of the class that creates the background task

```
    package com.asde.ipac;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.widget.Toast;

class AsyncLoadXML extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

   Context ctx;



   public AsyncLoadXML(Context c) {
      this.ctx = c;

   }

   @Override
   protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {



      try {
         writeXML(ctx);
      } catch (IOException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return null;
   }


   public void writeXML(Context ctx) throws IOException{   
      FileOutputStream fout = null;

      try {
         fout = ctx.openFileOutput("answers.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         Toast.makeText(ctx, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

      XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
      try {
         serializer.setOutput(fout, "UTF-8");
         serializer.startDocument(null, true);
         serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);

         serializer.startTag(null, "questions");

         serializer.startTag(null, "question");
         serializer.attribute(null,"grupo" , "test");
         serializer.attribute(null,"grupo" , "test");
         serializer.text("A");
         serializer.endTag(null, "question");



         serializer.endTag(null, "questions");


         serializer.endDocument();
         serializer.flush();
         fout.close();

         Toast.makeText(ctx, "write done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(ctx, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
   }



}
```

And this is the output of LogCat

```
    09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:324)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at com.asde.ipac.AsyncLoadXML.escribirXML(AsyncLoadXML.java:96)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at com.asde.ipac.AsyncLoadXML.doInBackground(AsyncLoadXML.java:43)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at com.asde.ipac.AsyncLoadXML.doInBackground(AsyncLoadXML.java:1)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-15 14:34:04.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):    ... 4 more
```

No really I'm doing wrong. Does the method OnPostExecute is mandatory?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to display Toasts in `doInBackground()` while UI operations are forbidden in this method.

What you should do is make all your processing inside this method, return the result of your processing, and then handle it in `onPostExecute()` and display the Toasts if necessary.

**EDIT**

Something like that : change the return value of `writeXML` :

```
public String writeXML(Context ctx) throws IOException{   
  FileOutputStream fout = null;

  try {
     fout = ctx.openFileOutput("answers.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     return e.getMessage();
  }

  XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
  try {
     serializer.setOutput(fout, "UTF-8");
     serializer.startDocument(null, true);
     serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);

     serializer.startTag(null, "questions");

     serializer.startTag(null, "question");
     serializer.attribute(null,"grupo" , "test");
     serializer.attribute(null,"grupo" , "test");
     serializer.text("A");
     serializer.endTag(null, "question");



     serializer.endTag(null, "questions");


     serializer.endDocument();
     serializer.flush();
     fout.close();

     return "write done";
  } catch (Exception e) {
     return e.getMessage();
  }
  }
```

Change also the return value of `doInBackground` : (you will have to change your `AsyncTask` declaration also : `class AsyncLoadXML extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>`)

```
   @Override

   protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
       String result = "";

       try {
           result = writeXML(ctx);
       } catch (IOException e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return result;
   }
```

And add the `onPostExecute` method :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(!result.equals("")) 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Be sure to use the application context (getApplicationContext()) when calling this.  Don't hang on to a reference to an Activity, when you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

See your logs:

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Add `Looper.prepare();` to your Thread where you run Handler

or

use iteration with Thread UI through handler, like:

```
private Handler mHandler = null;
protected static final int TOAST = 1;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String txt;
        switch (msg.what) {
        case TOAST:
            txt = msg.obj.toString();
            Toast.makeText(ctx, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;          
        default:
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }           



    }
};
```

Now you can show your toasts by using handler:

```
mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(TOAST, "write done"));
```

or

Like jbihan says put your logic where you show Toast under `onPostExecute()`

because under Toast under `doInBackground` drop you error

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike, sure, you can see Or, Or. Looper good for Thread not for Task